# Is it possible to call a method from a DotLiquid template?

Tags: dotliquid

Clearly, you can call properties, but calling a method doesn't do anything, even on a class that extends from Drop.

I'm trying to do something like this in my XmlDocumentDrop class.

```
public string XPath
{
  return xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
}
```

Then in my DotLiquid template.

```
{{ xmlDoc.XPath("//firstName") }}
```

This returns nothing.

I have tried to use the "CatchAll" method, but I'm trying to pass XPath, and it seems to strip out all non-word characters.  So, trying to do this:

```
{{ xmlDoc.//firstName }}
```

Just sends "firstName" to BeforeMethod.

I'm trying to template an XML document, using XPath to access data from the template.  Short of creating properties for every XPath I might need (not ideal, as the idea is to let users template an XML doc without having to involve a developer), what are my options?

I could do a filter, so something like this:

```
{{ xmlDoc|xpath:"//firstName" }}
```

But a filter only takes a string, which means I'm passing in the raw XML as a string, then re-parsing this XML every time it's called, which isn't great.

Options?

**Edit:**

I tried a custom tag too, but in the end, I'm still passing the XML as a string and re-parsing all the XML every time.  What I really need is a reference to the XML document in my template, and the ability to call a single method, passing in a string of XPath.

Comment: Hmm, that's a tricky one. The normal answer in this type of situation is `BeforeMethod`, but as you pointed out that won't work for XPath queries, which aren't valid identifiers. A filter might be the only solution, although it's not great.

Comment: Do you have a gut feeling on how big of a change this might be? I'd be willing to maintain a fork for it.

Comment: I got all the way down into Liquid.VariableParser.  The Regex in there will parse xmlDoc.XPath("//firstName") into (1) xmlDoc, (2) XPath, and (3) firstName.  Any change would have to mess with the core method of parsing variables, which I can't help but think is a painful change.

Comment: I moved this to the Google Group, as it's a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass XMLDoc as not a string. Simply create a Filter that accepts object like this:

```
public static Xpath(object document, string xpath)
{
   var xmlDoc = document as XmlDocumentDrop;
   return xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
}
```

That way you don't need to re-parse anything.